# Passing data from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I faced a question when I tried to proceed on passing data from my UITableView to the other UIViewController. What should I do on my "If" statement to be able to pass the data on each selected cell? Can you guys give me a hand?

***ViewController:***

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopSell: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
        @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewBanner: UICollectionView!


        var dataSource: [Content] = [Content]()
        var dataBanner: [Banner] = [Banner]()
        var dataTopSold: [Top10] = [Top10]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            //Delegate TableView
            self.tableViewTopSell.delegate = self
            //SetupNavBarCustom
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.CustomNavigationBar()
            let logo = UIImage(named: "tag.png")
            let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
            self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
            //CallAPIData
            getTopSold { (data) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dataTopSold = data
                    self.tableViewTopSell.reloadData()
                }
            }
            getBanner { (data) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dataBanner = data
                self.collectionViewBanner.reloadData()
                }
            }
            getAudiobooksAPI { (data) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dataSource = data
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
        //CollectionView
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
                return  self.dataSource.count
            }else{
                return self.dataBanner.count
            }}
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

            let content = self.dataSource[indexPath.item]

            cell.bookLabel.text = content.descricao
            cell.bookImage.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")

            return cell

            }else if (collectionView == self.collectionViewBanner) {

                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCellBanner", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

                let content = self.dataBanner[indexPath.item]

                cell.bannerImage.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")


                return cell
            }
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    //TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataTopSold.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topSoldCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        let content = self.dataTopSold[indexPath.item]
        cell.labelNomeTopSell.text = content.nome
        cell.imageViewTopSell.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")
        cell.labelPrecoDe.text = "R$ \(content.precoDe)"
        cell.labelPrecoPor.text = "R$ 119.99"
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueId", sender:self.dataTopSold[indexPath.item])

        }

        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            if segue.identifier == "segueId" {

                let des = segue.destination as! TelaDetalheProdutos

                des.stringNomeeDesc = sender as? String

            }
        }

    }

extension UIImageView{
    func setImage(url : String, placeholder: String, callback : (() -> Void)? = nil){
        self.image = UIImage(named: "no-photo")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: url)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            guard error == nil else{
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.image = image

                if let callback = callback{
                    callback()
                }


            })

        }).resume()
    }
}
```

***AudioBook file:***

```
import Foundation

//Categorias
struct Contents : Decodable {
    let data : [Content]
}
struct Content : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let descricao : String
    let urlImagem : String
}
//Banner
struct BannerData : Decodable {
    let data : [Banner]
}
struct Banner : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let urlImagem : String
    let linkUrl : String
}
//Top10
struct Top10Data:Decodable {
    let data: [Top10]
}
struct Top10:Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let nome : String
    let urlImagem : String
    let descricao : String
    let precoDe : Int
}
```

***Detail ViewController:***

```
import UIKit

class TelaDetalheProdutos: UIViewController {
    //Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelNomeEDesc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelDe: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelPor: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelNomeProduto: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelDescricao: UILabel!
    //Strings
    var stringImageView = String()
    var stringNomeeDesc = String()
    var stringLabelDe = String()
    var stringLabelPor = String()
    var stringNomeProduto = String()
    var stringlabeDescricao = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    ***//What should I do here?***

    }

}
```

***[Edit 1]:***

I'm doing this way, but I got this crash:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Top10' to type 'String'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topSoldCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let content = self.dataTopSold[indexPath.item]
    cell.labelNomeTopSell.text = content.nome
    cell.imageViewTopSell.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")
    cell.labelPrecoDe.text = "R$ \(content.precoDe)"
    cell.labelPrecoPor.text = "R$ 119.99"
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueId", sender:self.dataTopSold[indexPath.row])

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

         if segue.identifier == "segueId" {

        let des = segue.destination as! TelaDetalheProdutos

        des.stringNomeeDesc = sender as! Top10
    }
}
```

***[Edit 3]*** **-SOLVED** - What happened was that in Storyboard I linked the UITableViewCell to the other screen instead of linking the ViewController. That's why it appeared twice.

When the screen does the transition after select the cell, the next screen containing the results appear automatically twice. The first time it has empty fields and after 1 second or less there's another automatically transition once again, but this time containing all the data I've passed. The same occur when I click in the "back" TopBar button. What might be happening?

[image]

Comment: Pass the selected `indexPath` as as the `sender` instead of `self` And then you can use it in `prepareFor` to get the relevant object from your model and set it as a property on your destination view controller

Comment: Hello @Paulw11! Oh, wait. So, I pass the indexPath or IndexPath.row? After that, how about the if statement to say like: cell.labelName.text and etc?

Comment: You can pass the indexPath or the row. It doesn't matter as long a story you downcast it properly in `prepareFor`. The you can get the relevant object from `self.dataTopSold`

Comment: First, don't use `item`, use `row` when working with tables.  Second, what is the type of objects in the array?  They aren't strings so a forced downcast to a string is going to crash. Cast it to the right object class

Comment: Gotcha! The object type in the array they're all Strings and only one is Int. I just updated the post with the complete UIViewController file and also the AudioBook file, which contains all my structs. Could you check, please?

Comment: sh_khan's answer shows you what to do. In the `viewWillAppear` of the detailview controlller get the fields from the struct and put the values in your UI. You don't need all of those individual properties. Just pass the whole `Top10` struct instance

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you so much dude! It's working perfectly now. I appreciate your patience on helping me

Comment: @Paulw11 Man, I just updated the post with another error [Edit 3]. Could you try to help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueId", sender:self.dataTopSold[indexPath.row])

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "segueId" {

        let des = segue.destination as! TelaDetalheProdutos

        des.item = sender as! Top10
    }
}
```

//

```
class TelaDetalheProdutos: UIViewController {

   var item:Top10?

}
```

Comment: Hello! Oh, hold on. I get everything you did, unless the last part. So, I should say like: des. stringNomeeDesc = sender as! (as what?). How do I know if I'm passing the cell. labelNomeTopSell or etc?

Comment: Replace **What** with the data type of the array **dataTopSold** like when you declare array of strings **[String]** -> what will be **String** in your array it may be **struct** or class type replace it  , you actually don't pass the cell you pass the model or array item displayed in the cell when you click **didSelectRowAt** indexPath.row represents the index of the array the clicked cell is currently displaying

Comment: @BrunoVavretchek post declaration of **dataTopSold**

Comment: I'll post, hold on a sec please

Comment: I just updated with the complete UIViewController file and also the AudioBook file, which contains all my structs.

Comment: Well, in the next screen I gotta populate the following fileds: IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
    IBOutlet weak var labelNomeEDesc: UILabel!
    IBOutlet weak var labelDe: UILabel!
    IBOutlet weak var labelPor: UILabel!
    IBOutlet weak var labelNomeProduto: UILabel!
    IBOutlet weak var labelDescricao: UILabel!

Comment: I do have properties for each of them

Comment: I'll hold on please

Comment: Look to the answer carefully did you declared **var item:Top10?**--------**Cloneeeeeeeeeeeeeee it**

Comment: Man, thank you so much! Yeah, I forgot to declare the var item:Top10. Now I just said on Details View DidLoad:                 labelNomeProduto.text = item?.nome  and I got to populate, it's working perfectly!

Comment: Although your answer solved the problem, however I think you should use [Optional Chaining (?) as an alternative to Forced Unwrapping (!)](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) for these lines of code: `let des = segue.destination as! TelaDetalheProdutos`, `des.item = sender as! Top10`.

Comment: Hello @AnhPham! I'll adopt you changes, it would be really good once the data can be nill, correct? I also updated the main post with another question[Edit 3], could you try to help me please?

Comment: @Sh_Khan Man, I just updated the post with another error [Edit 3]. Could you try to help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Save the selected indexpath in did select

In prepare for segue get the data and pass it on to the DetailViewController

```
//in prepare for segue
let content = self.dataTopSold[indexPath.item]
//cast segue.destination controller to DetailViewController and pass content
guard let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController else {return}
detailViewController.content = content
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me, dude! I got to fix it